# Query works in SQLite3, but it is a syntax error in Microsoft SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sqlite, join

That query is:

```sql
SELECT 100.*COUNT(DISTINCT names_of_numbers.language_name)/variables.value
    AS "Percentage of Indo-European languages in which the words for 2 and 10 start with the same letter."
    FROM (names_of_numbers as numbers1),names_of_numbers,languages,variables
    WHERE variables.variable_name='Number of Indo-European languages' and numbers1.language_name=names_of_numbers.language_name
         and names_of_numbers.language_name=languages.language_name and languages.language_family='Indo-European' and
         substr(numbers1.word,1,1)=substr(names_of_numbers.word,1,1) and numbers1.value=2 and names_of_numbers.value=10;
```

Microsoft SQL server tells me there is a syntax error near `)` in the third line. What is going on here? How can I make that query in standard SQL?

Comment: SQL Server and SQLite are completely different products. You can't take code from one and dump it in the other and expect it to "just work".

Comment: Also, you do know it's 2021, right? The explicit JOIN syntax had been around for **29 years**. Why are you writing yours with that old 1980's syntax?

Comment: @Larnu What is `JOIN`? Where can I read more about it?

Comment: @Larnu Firefox and Chrome are completely different products, yet I expect JavaScript that works in one to work in the other.

Comment: @marc_s JQuery is, AFAIK, not a translation layer, it is a frameweork for building flashcard web-games, such as the one I made a few years ago: https://flatassembler.github.io/etymologist

Comment: Every different RDBMS uses a different dialect of SQL @FlatAssembler , they aren't the same language. They're based on the same idea, SQL, and they include many, but not all and often different, parts of the ANSI-SQL requirements, but other than that they are free to implement how the dialect how they want to. SQL Server specifically uses a dialect called T-SQL (Transact SQL) which SQLite does not use; it has its own dialect.

Comment: This, in essence, is very similar to how real languages work, there's many different dialects of English, for example. Unlike people, however, who can normally interpret what the intention is, syntax is code has to be precise. For example your attempt to use `SUBSTR` would be like an American writing "donut" to someone English, and the English person repling "don't know what a donut is" (it's doughnut in English). Or vice versa, the English person saying they have an Aluminium Can, and the American saying they don't know what "Aluminium" is (it's Aluminum in American).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get that error because of the parentheses here:

```
(names_of_numbers as numbers1)
```

Remove them.

Also, you must change `SUBSTR()` to [`SUBSTRING()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/substring-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) which is SQL Server's equivalent function, although for your case [`LEFT()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/left-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) would also work.

Also, since you are aggregating with `COUNT()` the column `variables.value` will not be allowed by SQL Server (SQLite allows it).
Instead use a subquery that returns `variables.value`.

Finally, use proper joins with aliases for all the tables and `ON` clauses:

```
SELECT 100.0 * COUNT(DISTINCT n2.language_name) / 
       (SELECT value FROM variables WHERE variable_name = 'Number of Indo-European languages') 
       AS [Percentage of Indo-European languages in which the words for 2 and 10 start with the same letter]
FROM names_of_numbers n1
INNER JOIN names_of_numbers n2 ON n2.language_name = n1.language_name
INNER JOIN languages l ON l.language_name = n2.language_name
WHERE n1.value = 2 AND n2.value = 10 AND SUBSTRING(n1.word, 1, 1) = SUBSTRING(n2.word, 1, 1) 
  AND l.language_family = 'Indo-European';
```